# AIR for desktop and Google's Speech to text API

Tags: actionscript-3, air, speech-recognition, desktop-application

Is anyone aware of a native Extension for Adobe AIR desktop that ties into Google's Speech API?

After a couple days of searching i have come across 2 ANE's but they both seem to be dependent on the Android OS. ie You must target and publish to an android based device for them to work

http://myappsnippet.com/google-speech-api-air-native-extension/

http://blog.immanuelnoel.com/2011/12/07/new-actionscript-native-extension-speech-recognition/

There is also this approach which works offline, but requires training and only works with 'pre canned' responses

http://www.bytearray.org/?p=1151

Here's a web example of Google's API
https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too tried the same thing for ios. But finally i found some FLAC file which integrates with Google API only. And this works a bit better for me in AIR too.

```
http://8byte8.com/blog/2012/07/voice-recognition-ios/
 just go through that URL, you will get some idea.


And the class which i made is .


package com.gmail.nxhoaf
{
    import com.adobe.audio.format.WAVWriter;
    import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSONDecoder;

    import flash.events.ErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.HTTPStatusEvent;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.events.SampleDataEvent;
    import flash.media.Microphone;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.net.FileReference;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    import flash.utils.Endian;

    import cmodule.flac.CLibInit;

    import fr.kikko.lab.ShineMP3Encoder;


    //import mx.controls.Alert;

    public class Recorder
    {
        public var CALL_BACK:Function; 

        private var bytes:ByteArray;
        private var mic:Microphone;
        private var mp3Encoder : ShineMP3Encoder;

        private static const FLOAT_MAX_VALUE:Number = 1.0;
        private static const SHORT_MAX_VALUE:int = 0x7fff;
        public function Recorder()
        {
        }

        public function setMicrophone (mic : Microphone) {
            this.mic = mic;
        }

        public function getMicrophone () {
            return mic;
        }

        public function startRecord() :void {
            this.bytes = new ByteArray();
            mic.gain = 100;
            mic.rate = 44;
            mic.setSilenceLevel(0,4000);                    
            // Remove playback listener if any
            mic.removeEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, onPlaying);
            // Add record listener
            mic.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, onRecording);
        }

        public function stopRecord() :void {
            mic.removeEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA,onRecording);
        }

        public function playback () :void {
            if (bytes.length > 0) {
                bytes.position = 0;
                var sound:Sound = new Sound();
                sound.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA,onPlaying);
                sound.play();
            }
        }

        private function onRecording(event:SampleDataEvent):void {
            while (event.data.bytesAvailable) {
                var sample:Number = event.data.readFloat();
                bytes.writeFloat(sample);
            }
        }

        private function onPlaying(event:SampleDataEvent): void {
            var sample:Number;
            for (var i:int = 0; i < 8192; i++) {
                if (!bytes.bytesAvailable) return;
                sample = bytes.readFloat();
                event.data.writeFloat(sample);
                event.data.writeFloat(sample);
            }
        }

        public function encodeToFlacAndSend() : void {  
            var flacCodec:Object;
            flacCodec = (new cmodule.flac.CLibInit).init();
            bytes.position = 0;
            var rawData: ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            var flacData : ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            rawData = convert32to16(bytes);
            flacData.endian = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN;
            //flacData.endian = Endian.BIG_ENDIAN

            flacCodec.encode( encodingCompleteHandler, encodingProgressHandler, rawData, flacData, rawData.length, 30);     

            function encodingCompleteHandler(event:*):void 
            {
                trace(flacData.length.toString(),"FLACCodec.encodingCompleteHandler(event):", event);
                //Alert.show(flacData.length.toString());           
                //var PATH:String = "https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=chromium&lang=en-IN";
                var PATH:String = "https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=chromium&lang=en-IN";

                var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(PATH);
                var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
                //urlRequest.contentType = "audio/x-flac; rate=44000";
                urlRequest.contentType = "audio/x-flac; rate=44000";
                urlRequest.data = flacData;

                urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
                urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY; // default
                urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, urlLoader_complete);
                urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, IOErrorOccured);
                urlLoader.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, urlLoader_error);
                urlLoader.load(urlRequest);

                function urlLoader_complete(evt:Event):void {
                    trace("MORTYYYYYYYY",urlLoader.data);
                    var dc:JSONDecoder = new JSONDecoder(String(urlLoader.data),true);
                    var ob:Object = dc.getValue(); 
                    var test:Array = ob["hypotheses"];

                    if(CALL_BACK != null){
                        if (test.length >=1){
                            CALL_BACK(test[0]["utterance"]);
                        }else {
                            CALL_BACK(null);
                        }
                    } 
                }
                function urlLoader_error(evt:ErrorEvent): void {
                    trace("*** speech to text *** " + evt.toString());
                    if(CALL_BACK != null){
                        CALL_BACK(null);
                    }
                }
                function IOErrorOccured(evt:IOErrorEvent): void {

                    trace("*** IO Error Occured *** " + evt.toString());
                    if(CALL_BACK != null){
                            CALL_BACK(null);
                    }
                }
                function onHTTPResponse(eve:HTTPStatusEvent):void{
                    trace("*** HTTP  Error Occured *** " + eve.toString());
                }

            }

            function encodingProgressHandler(progress:int):void {
                //              trace("FLACCodec.encodingProgressHandler(event):", progress);;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Converts an (raw) audio stream from 32-bit (signed, floating point) 
         * to 16-bit (signed integer).
         * 
         * @param source The audio stream to convert.
         */
        private function convert32to16(source:ByteArray):ByteArray {
            //          trace("BitrateConvertor.convert32to16(source)", source.length);

            var result:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            result.endian = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN;

            while( source.bytesAvailable ) {
                var sample:Number = source.readFloat() * SHORT_MAX_VALUE;

                // Make sure we don't overflow.
                if (sample < -SHORT_MAX_VALUE) sample = -SHORT_MAX_VALUE;
                else if (sample > SHORT_MAX_VALUE) sample = SHORT_MAX_VALUE;

                result.writeShort(sample);
            }

            //          trace(" - result.length:", result.length);
            result.position = 0;
            return result;
        }

        /**
         * Save recorded audio stream to a specific audio format
         * @param soundFormat: expected sound format
         */ 
        /*      public function saveAs(soundFormat: String) {
        switch(soundFormat) {           
        case SoundFormat.WAV:
        encodeToWav(bytes);
        break;
        case SoundFormat.MP3: 
        encodeToMp3(bytes);
        break;
        default:
        encodeToWav(bytes);
        break;
        }
        }*/

        /**
         * Encode recorded audio to .wav
         * @param inputStream stream which we want to encode 
         * 
         */ 
        private function encodeToWav(bytes:ByteArray) : void {
            var wav:WAVWriter = new WAVWriter();
            wav.numOfChannels = 1;
            wav.sampleBitRate = 16;
            wav.samplingRate =  44100;

            bytes.position = 0;
            var wavData : ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            wavData.endian = Endian.BIG_ENDIAN;
            wav.processSamples(wavData,bytes,44100,1);          
            //wavData.position = 0; 
            (new FileReference()).save(wavData, ".wav");
        }

        /**
         * Encode recorded audio to .mp3
         * @param inputStream stream which we want to encode  
         * 
         */ 
        private function encodeToMp3(bytes:ByteArray) : void {
            var wav:WAVWriter = new WAVWriter();
            wav.numOfChannels = 1;
            wav.sampleBitRate = 16;
            wav.samplingRate = 44100;

            bytes.position = 0;
            var wavData : ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            wavData.endian = Endian.BIG_ENDIAN;
            wav.processSamples(wavData,bytes,44100,1);          
            wavData.position = 0;

            mp3Encoder = new ShineMP3Encoder(wavData);
            mp3Encoder.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, mp3EncodeComplete);
            mp3Encoder.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, mp3EncodeProgress);
            mp3Encoder.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, mp3EncodeError);
            mp3Encoder.start();

            function mp3EncodeProgress(event : ProgressEvent) : void {
            }

            function mp3EncodeError(event : ErrorEvent) : void {
                //  Alert.show(event.toString());
            }

            function mp3EncodeComplete(event : Event) : void {
                //              mp3Encoder.saveAs();
            }
        }
    }
}
//import com.gmail.nxhoaf;
```